# Autorun script blocked me out

Tags: raspbian, script

I use my Raspberry pi to host a server. I made a script that starts the server and put it to   the /etc/rc.local file to autorun it at boot. 
My problem is that when I start the raspberry it runs the server, but I can't stop it. I tried ctrl+c, but it didn't work. So how can I stop it?

Comment: Are you using ctrl+c on the Pi?  If so try ctrl+alt+f1 to get a console, log in, edit /etc/rc.local and kill the running process or reboot.  ctrl+alt+f7 should return to the original console.

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: What kind of a "server"? Usually the script to start it should support stopping a service too. Ctrl+c is most likely not helping much as your server is running in the background being not connected to the terminal. As suggested by joan you should figure out the PID of the process in another shell (see `man ps`) and kill it. A proper start up script should provide a PID-file to simplify this task.

Comment: It is connected to terminal, but it hasn't any exit command. I also tried to open a new shell but it only gave me a black screen with cursor in it.

Comment: The more brutal approach is to power down.  Edit the SD card in another machine.  Change cmdline.txt. Add init=/bin/sh to the end of the line of text and save the file.  Reboot.  Change /etc/rc.local.  Re-edit cmdline.txt to remove init=/bin/sh and reboot.